# How to check if some macro defined via \csname is empty?

Tags: conditionals, programming

I need to check whether my macro `\csname creator1\endcsname` empty or not. But I always get `1`(not empty)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\creator}[1]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname creator1\endcsname{#1}
}
\makeatother

\creator{}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

    \csname creator1\endcsname

    \ifx\csname creator1\endcsname\@empty 0\else 1\fi

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

UPD:

Thanks to comments, I realize, I forget  `\expandafter` before `\ifx`. But If I use `\expandafter\ifx\csname creator2\endcsname\@empty` instead, I get `not empty` again. Interestig thing, `\csname creator2\endcsname` was not defined before

Comment: you are missing an \expandafter: \expandafter\ifx\csname creator1\endcsname\@empty

Comment: `\expandafter\ifx`. Right now you are comparing `\csname` and `c`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting, if I \expandafter\ifx\csname creator2\endcsname\@empty I get not empty again. But \csname creator2\endcsname is not difined

Comment: well "not defined" is not the same as "\@empty". So getting 1 is the right answer to your test.

Comment: `\csname` makes the command `\let` to `\relax` if it is not already defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I realized. Now I get what I want.